# OOD in C++: Having a class with just one method?

Tags: c++, function, class, methods, object-oriented-analysis

I'm writing a program in C++, and with Object Oriented Design in mind, that keeps a record of used cars in a database. I have a function that sorts the cars by year, but should that function be a method in its own class, a method in the car class, or just a function outside of any class? We were taught that in Object Oriented Design, everything should be in it's own class, and that each class should only have one responsibility, so I'm leaning towards having the function as a method in it's own class, but it seems unnecessary. What should I do?

Comment: also, would that class with only a method require a constructor, even if the class contains no data members?

Comment: What kind of container do you use for the cars (e.g array)? And are you familiar with the standard library containers (e.g. `vector<Car>`)?

Comment: @beta it will be an array for the cars, yes. And sorry, I'm not familiar with that, I have an extremely limited knowledge of classes and object oriented design in c++

Comment: @beta I have only been taught to use "using namespace std" if that applies to what you're saying

Comment: The best tip to you I have to offer is to stop thinking of OOP/OOD of being some sacred matter of nearly religious dimension. Design is driven by a lot of factors, last not least the needs of a team which has to work together smoothly. There is no OO method which can prove that one partitioning of a problem is more correct than another. Also, OOP does not mean that anything has to be in a class. Classes are abstractions when they are useful. But not a "must". Nothing could e.g. be said against a method: ``void SortByAge( CarList& cars );`` or ``CarList SortByAge( const CarList&cars);``

Comment: Just as an aside, once you learn what "using namespace std;" means, you'll see that it's a handy shortcut in early editing, but not a good idea in finished code. A lot of what they teach in programming courses is not good practice in the real world.

Comment: @Trevor you can accept an answer by clicking `tick` if you found the solution. otherwise comment on the answers to know more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be a function on its own, not a member of any class. Something like this:

```
void sortCars(Car * lot, unsigned int numCars)
  ...
```

There is no point in wrapping this in a class that has no other members; doing so would solve no problem and make nothing easier.

There is no point in making it a member of `Car`, and doing so would give it access to private members of the class which it doesn't need, which is asking for trouble.

"Everything should be in its own class" is a crude guideline, and more applicable to nouns (`Car`) than to verbs (`sortCars`).

Answer (score 3):

Even though i would favor using a simple function to do the job and put it in the some namespace like

```
namespace CarUtils {
    void sort(Car *carsArr, const size_t & arrSize) {
        // code ...
     }
};
```

However, as you would learn more things like STL and features like `algorithms` and `vectors`, you would find `sort` algorithm inbuild.

Now you just need to give your `comparison function-objects` :

```
namespace CarUtils {  // i would still put things in namespace :)
       struct SortByMileage {
              bool operator()(const Car & c1, const Car & c2) {
                  return c1.mileage < c2.mileage;
              }
       };

       struct SortByYear {
              bool operator()(const Car & c1, const Car & c2) {
                  return c1.purchaseDate.year < c2.purchaseDate.year;
              }
       };
};
```

and then in your code :

```
// #include <algorithm>  // include this file.
std::sort(cars, cars + sizeOfCarArr, CarUtils::SortByMileage());
// and to sort by year
std::sort(cars, cars + sizeOfCarArr, CarUtils::SortByYear());
```

This approach is better since, truthfully, you should not be writing sort function again and again for the different kinds of sorting like by-mileage, or by-capacity etc..

But.. again to come to our philosophy of using only functions where functions are required.. we can use lambdas (C++11 feature) :)

```
std::sort(cars, cars + sizeOfCarArr, [](const Car & c1, const Car & c2) {
       return c1.mileage < c2.mileage;
});

std::sort(cars, cars + sizeOfCarArr, [](const Car & c1, const Car & c2) {
       return c1.purchaseDate.year < c2.purchaseDate.year;
});
```

to use C++11 you need to pass `-std=c++11` to the compiler.

Answer (score -1):

As @meet said, try to avoid having global functions. Also, I think it's important to determine what type of relationship the database has with the cars.

It seems to me for example that a used car has-a (as opposed to is-a, which would get into inheritance) database, and thus, it can be implemented as a separate function rather than a class of its own!

Comment: how can a car `has a` database ?

Comment: because a database is an attribute of the class of cars? you haven't have a database of used cars without any cars.

Comment: database would be containing cars information like age etc.. this age would be a member/attribute of car. Class can contain methods for accessing this attribute.. but to do anything with this attribute like (sorting) is not the property of a Car.. and it should not be part of the class.